# Java Data Base Overflow?

Tags: java, database, jdbc

My code is simple, it generates a Data Base to store certain data (obviously), but the problem resides in the fact that it would create an "overflow" of DBs becuase every time the class ran it would generate another Data Base, I heard of a command:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS insertYourFavoriteName;
```

But some people say that why should I need a DB for each computer, when I could just do a central one when users conect, but correct me if I'm wrong, that would make the app depend on internet, right?

So in resume here are the 2 questions:

1. Does the command mentioned above works? Or does a better version or way to work around it exists?
2. Data Bases where all users connect to it mean that you need a server, and as a consecuence your app would depend on internet?

Comment: Sorry, but your question is very, very broad. I would suggest to google "In Memory database" for a start, but it seems you need one that supports multiple clients and then the problem will not be to start it (if no db is there, start it) but when to end it... anyway, your will probably have to ask more specific questions to get a good answer. Of course you could also require a database, for example mysql, to be running on every computer already...

Comment: Are you sure, you need a Database on every single computer? What should be saved in there?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to learn about databases you practice basic CRUD operations on that database. After that do some sample applications on database

If you want to create a database if not exists in mysql simply use this `CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS DBName;`

Basically before checking all these things you have to have basic understanding of what is database and how it works, So, please go through some good resources and get good understanding on the concepts.